# Split TCP, UDP packet data

Tags: c#, packet, pcap, pcap.net

I am using PcapDot.Net project's DLLs and I am try to split TCP and UDP packet data.

For example if my payload length is 20 bytes, I want to split this into 2 pieces of 10 bytes.

Of course the Ethernet layer, IPv4 layer and the transport layer remain the same, I only fix this checksum.

So this works fine with UDP and if my packet's payload is 100 bytes after play the new 2 packets I can see 2 packets each on them with payload length of 50 bytes.

My problem is with TCP in this case if my payload is 100 bytes after play the new 2 packets I can see 2 packets but in this case without any payload and Wireshark notice that every packet exept the first is seen as a TCP Retransmition.

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my function that split the data:

```
private IEnumerable<Packet> SplitPacketData(Packet packet, List<List<byte>> lists)
        {
            EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
            IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
            DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
            TransportLayer transportlayer = GetTransportLayer(packet);

            if (transportlayer == null)
            {
                yield return packet;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (List<byte> list in lists)
                {
                    ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
                    transportlayer.Checksum = null;
                    PayloadLayer payloadLayer = new PayloadLayer
                    {
                        Data = new Datagram(list.ToArray())
                    };

                    yield return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, transportlayer, payloadLayer);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: TCP packets contain sequence numbers also so that replays can be detected and reassembly can occur. Are you fiddling the sequence numbers also?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to split packets?

Comment: It's not a good idea to mess with TCP packets. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @CodeCaster Packet splitting is a valid pen test operation: some application layer firewalls / loadbalancers etc. may fail to spot certain types of activity if it's suitably split.

Comment: @Nathan sure, I'm just asking OP so they can provide some background information. As of now, the question borders on _"Too broad"_, as we seem to need to explain TCP fundamentals to OP and work our way up to the Pcap.Net-library.

Comment: no, i did not fidding sequence numbers, in case i have 2 packets this sould be 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @mikiwess, please learn about TCP sequence numbers and ack numbers and the different TCP flags before attempting this. You will need to change some TCP fields when splitting a TCP packet as unlike UDP, TCP packets are not independent.